# Logo aligned left desktop / Then Centered on mobile - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've taken a break from HTML & css and now i'm trying to do my new website using bootstrap framework.

I need my logo to sit left on desktop devices but then centered along with the text on the right as well for mobile... I'm having so much trouble trying to figure this out. could someone please help! thanks!

```
<div class="container">
<header id="headertop">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-xs-12">
        <div class="logo-top"> 
        <a href="index.html"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/ejc-logo.png"/> </a> 
        </div> <!-- // end .logo-top --> 

    </div> <!-- // end .col LOGO -->


    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">

        <div class="contact-info-top">
            <span class="contact-phone hidden-sm hidden-xs"> 973.452.9716 </span> <br> 
            <span class="contact-email hidden-sm hidden-xs"> support@ejuicecrafters.com </span> 

            <div class="contact-info-top-mobile text-center">

            <h5 class="contact-phone-mobile hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xl"> 973.452.9716 </span> <br> 
            <h5 class="contact-email-mobile hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xl"> support@ejuicecrafters.com </span> 

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS File:

```
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
     .img-responsive {
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        left: 50%;
        position: absolute;
      }
    }
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/YL64euYYAZ

Answer (score 1):

I have simplified your code. Please check the result. What do you need to improve?

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .logo-top img {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .contact-info-top .contact-phone,
  .contact-info-top .contact-email { 
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .contact-info-top { 
    /* add what you need */
  }
  .contact-info-top .contact-phone { 
    /* add what you need */
  }
  .contact-info-top .contact-email { 
    /* add what you need */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header id="headertop">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 logo-top">
        <a href="index.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/c69/fff/?text=logo" /></a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 contact-info-top">
        <div class="contact-phone"> 973.452.9716 </div>
        <div class="contact-email"> support@ejuicecrafters.com </div> 
      </div>

    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work....

```
<div class="container">
    <header id="headertop">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
            <div class="logo-top"> 
            <a href="index.html"> <img class="img-responsive" src="images/ejc-logo.png"/> </a> 
            </div> <!-- // end .logo-top --> 

        </div> <!-- // end .col LOGO -->


        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">

            <div class="contact-info-top">
                <span class="contact-phone hidden-sm hidden-xs"> 973.452.9716 </span> <br> 
                <span class="contact-email hidden-sm hidden-xs"> support@ejuicecrafters.com </span> 

                <div class="contact-info-top-mobile text-center">

                <h5 class="contact-phone-mobile hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xl"> 973.452.9716 </span> <br> 
                <h5 class="contact-email-mobile hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xl"> support@ejuicecrafters.com </span> 

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```